Distinct for jsonb_path_query_array
Have some trouble with jsonb_path_query_array in pgsql.
Is there a way to distinct values inside arrays?
I have something like this
select jsonb_path_query_array(public.table.column, '$.Idents.type' ) from public.table;

And get output like this:
[1] [Type1, Type1, Type1, Type2, Type2, Type2]
[2] [Type3, Type3, Type3, Type4, Type4]

Is there a way to get something like this?
[1] [Type1, Type2]
[2] [Type3, Type4]

So, basically i need a distinct thing but inside processing array.
Is there a way to do this with some arg i didn't think about?

please make a [mre] with CREATE TABLE and INSERT IINTO

My mistake, sorry
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/14796

You can put it in a subquery, and run a (select jsonb_agg(distinct e) from jsonb_path_query(j)e) in there.

directly you can not use DISTINCT, but a Combination from jsonb_path_query  and array_agg would do the trick
Still you would need a unique column to do my approach
Schema (PostgreSQL v14)
create table public.example(id int,test jsonb);
insert into public.example (id, test) values (1, '{"Idents": [{"id": "id0", "type": "Type1"}, {"id": "id1", "type": "Type1"}, {"id": "id2", "type": "Type2"}, {"id": "id3", "type": "Type2"}], "val0": 1725397140, "val1": -10800}');
insert into public.example (id,test) values (2,'{"Idents": [{"id": "id4", "type": "Type3"}, {"id": "id5", "type": "Type3"}, {"id": "id6", "type": "Type4"}, {"id": "id6", "type": "Type4"}], "val0": 1725397140, "val1": -10800}');


Query #1
WITH CTE AS (select DISTINCT id ,jsonb_path_query(public.example.test, '$.Idents.type' ) val
from public.example)
SELECT id, array_agg(val)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY id;




id
array_agg




1
Type1,Type2


2
Type4,Type3




View on DB Fiddle
#A better solution would be to use jsonb_agg instead, like described in the comment
Schema (PostgreSQL v14)
create table public.example(id int,test jsonb);
insert into public.example (id, test) values (1, '{"Idents": [{"id": "id0", "type": "Type1"}, {"id": "id1", "type": "Type1"}, {"id": "id2", "type": "Type2"}, {"id": "id3", "type": "Type2"}], "val0": 1725397140, "val1": -10800}');
insert into public.example (id,test) values (2,'{"Idents": [{"id": "id4", "type": "Type3"}, {"id": "id5", "type": "Type3"}, {"id": "id6", "type": "Type4"}, {"id": "id6", "type": "Type4"}], "val0": 1725397140, "val1": -10800}');


Query #1
WITH CTE AS (select DISTINCT id ,jsonb_path_query(public.example.test, '$.Idents.type' ) val
from public.example)
SELECT id, jsonb_agg(val)
FROM CTE
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY id;




id
jsonb_agg




1
Type1,Type2


2
Type4,Type3




View on DB Fiddle

jsonb_path_query_array() returns a jsonb with a JSON array in it, not a SQL array with jsonb's in it. It would make sense to trade array_agg() for jsonb_agg() to match that.

This is the answer. Thank you!
